# Using Flink sql to emit to kafka with buffering producing null pointer exception

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a sql defined this way

```
  
CREATE TABLE raw_table
(
    headers     VARCHAR,
    id          VARCHAR,
    eventTimestamp  TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) NOT NULL,
    type        VARCHAR,
    contentJson VARCHAR,
    WATERMARK FOR eventTimestamp AS eventTimestamp - INTERVAL '5' SECONDS
) WITH (
      'connector' = 'kafka',
      'topic-pattern' = 'role__.+?',
      'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:29092,localhost:39092',
      'properties.group.id' = 'role_local_1',
      'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
      'format' = 'json',
      'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',
      'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
      'sink.parallelism' = '3',
      'sink.buffer-flush.interval' = '10s',
      'sink.buffer-flush.max-rows' = '1000'
      );

create view ROLES_NORMALIZED as
(
select 
       JSON_VALUE(contentJson, '$.id')                                 as id,
       rr.type                                                         as type
from raw_table rr
    );



CREATE VIEW ROLES_UPSERTS_V1 AS
(
SELECT *
FROM ROLES_NORMALIZED
WHERE type in ('ROLE_CREATED', 'ROLE_UPDATED')
    );


CREATE VIEW ROLES_DELETED_V1 AS
(
SELECT org,
       pod,
       tenantId,
       id,
       modified,
       modified as deleted,
       event_timestamp
FROM ROLES_NORMALIZED
WHERE type in ('ROLES_DELETED')
    );

-------


CREATE TABLE final_topic
(
    event_timestamp         TIMESTAMP_LTZ,
    id                      VARCHAR,
    name                    VARCHAR,
    deleted                 TIMESTAMP_LTZ,
    PRIMARY KEY (pod, org, id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
      'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
      'topic' = 'final_topic',
      'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:29092,localhost:39092',
      'properties.group.id' = 'some-group-id',
      'value.format' = 'json',
      'key.format' = 'json',
      'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',
      'properties.replication.factor' = '3',
      'value.json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
      'sink.parallelism' = '3'
      );


INSERT INTO final_topic
select 
       GREATEST(r.event_timestamp, d.event_timestamp) as event_timestamp,
       r.id,
       r.name,
       d.deleted
from ROLES_UPSERTS_V1 r
         LEFT JOIN ROLES_DELETED_V1 d
                   ON r.id = d.id;
```

When i use `'sink.buffer-flush.interval' = '10s'`,`'sink.buffer-flush.max-rows' = '1000'` these option on the sink, i see null point exception on the line (145) `wrappedContext.setTimestamp(value.f1);` in class `ReducingUpsertWriter`. This is happening because the `context` object timestamp() method is returning null, which is here `https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.16.0/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/table/ReducingUpsertWriter.java#L85`.
I have defined a event time attribute using `eventTimestamp  TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) NOT NULL,` and water mark using  `WATERMARK FOR eventTimestamp AS eventTimestamp - INTERVAL '5' SECONDS` .

when using flink sql what else do i need to define so that tha context.timestamp() method return a non null value. I am using flink version 1.16.0.

in example message i am sending to the source topic, `eventTimestamp` is not null.

Exception I see

```
2023-07-09 12:57:38
java.io.IOException: Could not perform checkpoint 2 for operator SinkMaterializer[44] -> Sink: Writer (3/3)#1.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.triggerCheckpointOnBarrier(StreamTask.java:1238)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.checkpointing.CheckpointBarrierHandler.notifyCheckpoint(CheckpointBarrierHandler.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.checkpointing.CheckpointBarrierTracker.triggerCheckpointOnAligned(CheckpointBarrierTracker.java:301)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.checkpointing.CheckpointBarrierTracker.processBarrier(CheckpointBarrierTracker.java:141)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.checkpointing.CheckpointedInputGate.handleEvent(CheckpointedInputGate.java:181)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.checkpointing.CheckpointedInputGate.pollNext(CheckpointedInputGate.java:159)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:542)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:831)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:780)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:914)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:728)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:550)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.table.ReducingUpsertWriter.flush(ReducingUpsertWriter.java:145)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.table.ReducingUpsertWriter.flush(ReducingUpsertWriter.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.sink.SinkWriterOperator.prepareSnapshotPreBarrier(SinkWriterOperator.java:167)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.prepareSnapshotPreBarrier(RegularOperatorChain.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.checkpointState(SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.java:334)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$performCheckpoint$13(StreamTask.java:1281)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.performCheckpoint(StreamTask.java:1269)
    at org.apache.flink
```

More updates

1. The issue seems to happen when `view` are used to transform the source table data. Somehow the record's timestamp is null.

is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that was tracked under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-25916 - If you upgrade your Flink Kafka Connector to 3.0.0, the issue will be resolved.

Comment: I am using flink cluster 1.16, cant upgrade to 1.17 yet. I only see `3.0.0-1.17` in mvnrepository. When i tried to use it. I get 
`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_UNALIGNED_SOURCE_SPLITS at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcherManager.<init>(SplitFetcherManager.java:143)`

Comment: This bug is only resolved with Flink 1.17 and onwards, and not for older versions.