# Using flink upsert-kafka connector is there a way to avoid intermediate messages being written to output kafka topic

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a kafka source that send event like record_created and record_updated. I perform some transformation and join other kafka topic to this source. Finally emit to a kafka topic.
I am using upset-kafka connector. How do I avoid all the intermediate state from being emitted.
These intermediate state of event are not complete or information in it is not accurate.

My sink config looks like this

```
    'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
    'topic' = '${output_topic_name}',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '${sink_kafka_servers}',
    'value.format' = 'json',
    'key.format' = 'json',
    'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',
    'properties.num.partitions' = '${sink_properties_num_partitions}',
    'value.json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
    'sink.parallelism' = '${sink_parallelism}'
```

`sink.buffer-flush` could help, but i am issue reported here : [Using Flink sql to emit to kafka with buffering producing null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76648744/using-flink-sql-to-emit-to-kafka-with-buffering-producing-null-pointer-exception/76666040#76666040)

For example If send a `record_created` ( this also have other fields in it), I get this message as out

```
{
  "eventTimestamp": "2023-01-01T04:01:01.284Z",
  "id": "role-id-where-2",
  "name": "G Even Role",
  "description": "G Even Role",
  "segments": [
    {
      "id": "seg-id-5",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "id": "seg-id-4",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "id": "seg-id-3",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "id": "seg-id-1",
      "name": null
    }
  ],
  "segmentCount": 4
}
```

Now i send a `record_updated` and field called `name` is changed to `updated role again name` I get 2 new event in output topic.

I get the previous event +

```
{
  "eventTimestamp": "2023-01-03T04:02:01.284Z",
  "id": "role-id-where-2",
  "name": "updated role again name",
  "description": "G Even Role",
  "segments": [
    {
      "id": "seg-id-5",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "id": "seg-id-4",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "id": "seg-id-3",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "id": "seg-id-1",
      "name": null
    }
  ],
  "segmentCount": 4
}
```

is there any other way to avoid this intermediate message ?

Answer (score 0):

As explained [in your other Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76648744/using-flink-sql-to-emit-to-kafka-with-buffering-producing-null-pointer-exception) you will need to upgrade your Flink version to at least Flink 1.17, so you can use that version where this bug has been fixed and you will be able to use `sink.buffer-flush`

Comment: Thank you, sink.buffer-flush introduces a delay which is not desirable. Any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: You don't want to have intermediate messages, but you also don't want a delay. Those are conflicting requirements, because how can Flink know that a message is an intermediate message if it has to process it immediately?

Comment: I don’t understand how flink join the data internally. I can’t think of reason on when those intermediate message would be useful to the end user. Looks like no other way out of it. Thank you

Comment: Internally it's a changelog stream. The intermediate message might be a requirement because you want to replicate exactly as the input source has been. It's just a different use case